# How to set password visible on click of icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome-5

I have three input fields all of them are password fields what i am trying to do is to put and `fontawesome` icon inside the input field on click which shows or hide the password

currently i have this but with button,and its doing only for one field not for all three fields, do i have to call 3 different functions for all three or it can be done with same function

**snippet**

```js
function show() {
  var a = document.getElementById("confirm_password");
  var b = document.getElementById("display2");
  if (a.type == "password") {
    a.type = "text";

  } else {
    a.type = "password";

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <h5 id="commonHeader">Current Password</h5>
  <input type="password" id="currentPass" name="currentpass" class="commanClass" placeholder="Current Password">
  <button type="button" onclick="show()" id="display"></button>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <h5 id="commonHeader">New Password</h5>
  <input type="password" id="newPass" name="newpass" required="required" class="commanClass" placeholder="Current Password">
  <button type="button" onclick="show()" id="display1"></button>

</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <h5 id="commonHeader">Confirm Password</h5>
  <input type="password" id="confirm_password" required="required" placeholder="Confirm Password">
  <button type="button" onclick="show()" id="display2"></button>
</div>

<div>
  <hr>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" id="save" class="commonButton">Save</button>
  <button type="button" id="save" class="commonButton">Clear</button>
</div>
```

in my snippet i have 3 input fields to all of which i have to provide a icon on which if user click it will show the password of current field

Currently it is working for one field only

Comment: You can pass an argument inside function call and make it dynamic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use removeAttribute to remove the type="password" and use setAttribute to set type as text simultaneously

```js
function show(a) {
  var x=document.getElementById(a);
  var c=x.nextElementSibling
  if (x.getAttribute('type') == "password") {
  c.removeAttribute("class");
  c.setAttribute("class","fas fa-eye");
  x.removeAttribute("type");
    x.setAttribute("type","text");
  } else {
  x.removeAttribute("type");
    x.setAttribute('type','password');
 c.removeAttribute("class");
  c.setAttribute("class","fas fa-eye-slash");
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <h5 id="commonHeader">Current Password</h5>
  <input type="password" id="currentPass" name="currentpass" class="commanClass" placeholder="Current Password">
  <i onclick="show('currentPass')" class="fas fa-eye-slash" id="display"></i>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <h5 id="commonHeader">New Password</h5>
  <input type="password" id="newPass" name="newpass" required="required" class="commanClass" placeholder="Current Password">
 <i onclick="show('newPass')" class="fas fa-eye-slash" id="display"></i>

</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <h5 id="commonHeader">Confirm Password</h5>
  <input type="password" id="confirm_password" required="required" placeholder="Confirm Password">
 <i onclick="show('confirm_password')" class="fas fa-eye-slash" id="display"></i>
</div>

<div>
  <hr>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" id="save" class="commonButton">Save</button>
  <button type="button" id="save" class="commonButton">Clear</button>
</div>
```

Comment: can you help me like how can i have a eye icon using font-awesome instead of that button, i have tried but not succeed

Comment: hey its working but look at the eye when i click on second one the first eye gets open

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make it dynamic for all then you need to pass the id of the textbox on function call and then you can use that id to perform logic dynamically.

```js
function show(id) {
  var a = document.getElementById(id);
  if (a.type == "password") {
    a.type = "text";

  } else {
    a.type = "password";

  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <h5 id="commonHeader">Current Password</h5>
  <input type="password" id="currentPass" name="currentpass" class="commanClass" placeholder="Current Password">
  <button type="button" onclick="show('currentPass')" id="display"></button>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <h5 id="commonHeader">New Password</h5>
  <input type="password" id="newPass" name="newpass" required="required" class="commanClass" placeholder="Current Password">
  <button type="button" onclick="show('newPass')" id="display1"></button>

</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <h5 id="commonHeader">Confirm Password</h5>
  <input type="password" id="confirm_password" required="required" placeholder="Confirm Password">
  <button type="button" onclick="show('confirm_password')" id="display2"></button>
</div>

<div>
  <hr>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" id="save" class="commonButton">Save</button>
  <button type="button" id="save" class="commonButton">Clear</button>
</div>
```

Comment: can you help me in,how can i use font-awesome icon inside  the input field instead of button please

Comment: @viveksingh are you using bootstrap?

Comment: yup bootstrap..you can help me with that

Comment: @viveksingh or if you dont want to use bootstrap and want to use your own css then you can try this http://jsfiddle.net/ethanpil/ws1g27y3/

Answer (score 1):

```js
function show(inputId) {
  var a = document.getElementById(inputId);
  if (a.type === "password") {
    a.type ="text";

  } else {
    a.type ="password";

  }
}
```

```css
.show-button{
  position:absolute;
  right:22px;
  top: 32px;
  border:0px;
  background-color:transparent;
}
input{
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-12 ">
  <h5 id="commonHeader">Current Password</h5>
  <input type="password" id="currentPass" name="currentpass" class="commanClass" placeholder="Current Password">
  <button class="show-button" type="button" onclick="show('currentPass')" id="display"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
</div>
<div class="col-12">
  <h5 id="commonHeader">New Password</h5>
  <input type="password" id="newPass" name="newpass" required="required" class="commanClass" placeholder="Current Password">
  <button type="button" class="show-button" onclick="show('newPass')" id="display1"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>

</div>
<div class="col-12">
  <h5 id="commonHeader">Confirm Password</h5>
  <input type="password" id="confirm_password" required="required" placeholder="Confirm Password">
  <button class="show-button" type="button" onclick="show('confirm_password')" id="display2"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
</div>

<div>
  <hr>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" id="save" class="commonButton">Save</button>
  <button type="button" id="save" class="commonButton">Clear</button>
</div>
```

Pass the id of the input in your function and you will be good. Hope it helps.

Comment: can you help me with how to put eye font-awesome icon inside that input field rather then buttons outside

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a single function which takes inputElementId as argument:

```
function show(inputElementId) {
  var a = document.getElementById(inputElementId);
  if (a.type == "password") {
    a.type = "text";

  } else {
    a.type = "password";

  }
}
```

You can call it 3 times like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <h5 id="commonHeader">Current Password</h5>
  <input type="password" id="currentPass" name="currentpass" class="commanClass" placeholder="Current Password">
  <button type="button" onclick="show(currentPass)" id="display"></button>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <h5 id="commonHeader">New Password</h5>
  <input type="password" id="newPass" name="newpass" required="required" class="commanClass" placeholder="Current Password">
  <button type="button" onclick="show(newPass)" id="display1"></button>

</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <h5 id="commonHeader">Confirm Password</h5>
  <input type="password" id="confirm_password" required="required" placeholder="Confirm Password">
  <button type="button" onclick="show(confirm_password)" id="display2"></button>
</div>

<div>
  <hr>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" id="save" class="commonButton">Save</button>
  <button type="button" id="save" class="commonButton">Clear</button>
</div>
```